# Keras sample_weight array error

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation, data-science

I'm working on a brain lesion segmentation problem and I'm trying to implement a Unet with code inspired by: https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation

One of the issues I'm trying to overcome is class balance (lots more non-lesion voxels rather than lesion voxels). I tried using class_balance but that didn't work so now I'm trying to use sample_weight and that's also giving me all sorts of errors.

First thing I tried was to set `sample_weight_mode` to `temporal` and feed in a weight matrix of the same shape as my target data:

```
target_data.shape -> (n_samples,512 rows/pixels, 512 cols/pixels, 1 channel)
Weight_map.shape -> (n_samples,512 rows/pixels, 512 cols/pixels, 1 channel)
```

Output:

> _ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (100, 512, 512, 1). In order to use timestep-wise sample weighting, you should pass a 2D sample_weight array.*

Second thing I tried was to flatten the sample array so it would be of shape:

```
Weight_map.shape -> (n_samples,512x512x1).
```

Output:

> ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (100, 262144) for an input with shape (100, 512, 512, 1). sample_weight cannot be broadcast.*

Next I tried following the advice of uschmidt83 ([here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3653)) and flattening the output of my model along with the corresponding target data.

```
last_layer = keras.layers.Flatten()(second_last_layer)

target_data.shape -> (n_samples,512x512x1).
Weight_map.shape -> (n_samples,512x512x1).
```

Output:

> ValueError: Found a sample_weight array for an input with shape (100, 262144). Timestep-wise sample weighting (use of sample_weight_mode="temporal") is restricted to outputs that are at least 3D, i.e. that have a time dimension.*

Oddly enough, even if I set `sample_weight=None` I still get the same error as right above.

Any advice on how to fix this sample_weight error? Here is the basic code to reproduce the error:
https://gist.github.com/andreimouraviev/2642384705034da92d6954dd9993fb4d

Also, if you have advice about how to deal the class imbalance problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Weight needs to be a 1D array, where as target has an extra channel like input.

Can you try `sample_weight_mode=temporal` with the following dimensions:

```
input_image  ->  (n_samples, 512, 512, 1)
target_label ->  (n_samples, 262144, 1)
weight_map   ->  (n_samples, 262144)
```

The following link contains information about class weights:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2115